# What is the optimization metric if the goal is to allocate each person the fewest number of types given several types of items.

Tags: optimization

It is really hard for me to describe my optimization goal. If anyone finds a better title, please just replace it.

Here is an example of my optimization problem. We have 3 people: A,B,C, and we have 5 apples, 5 bananas, and 3 pears. The constraint is that each person should get at least 4 fruits. If we index people with i and fruits with j, and $x_{ij}$ denotes the number of $j$th fruit allocated for the $i$th person. The constraint should be 
$$\sum_{j=1}^3 x_{ij} >= 4, ~~i=1,2,3$$
Our goal is to try our best to allocate the same type of fruit to just one person. So the solution can be A: 4 apples, B: 4 bananas, C: 3 pears + 1 apple. It can also be: A: 4 bananas, B: 4 apples, C: 3 pears + 1 banana, so many alternative optimal solution in this case. Let's say the metric is
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 |N_i - 1|,$$
where $N_i$ stands for the number of types for $i$th person. But how to mathematically model $N_i$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the first person gets 1 type of item, the second gets 1 type of item, and the third gets 3 types of items, is it better or worse than if they get 1, 2, and 2 types respectively?

Comment: @Rahul Just updated the post and added a metric, basically we consider your two cases equivalent.

Comment: $N_i = |\{j:x_{ij}\ne0\}| = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^3\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x_{ij}\ne0$,}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. This is sometimes called the $L^0$ norm, $\|\mathbf x_i\|_0$, if $\mathbf x_i=\begin{bmatrix}x_{i1}\\x_{i2}\\x_{i3}\end{bmatrix}$.